# How to "Fill" a GridViewColumn with ComboBox (WPF)?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview, combobox

I am looking for a way to "completely fill" a `GridViewColumn` with a combo box. I am able to create a cell template with `ComboBox` and it is working fine. But the width and height of `ComboBox` is not aligned with the `GridViewColumn`. 
Even if I try to set the same height/width `GridViewColumn` hides some part of the comboBox.

There must be some setting or style to instruct WPF to fill the `ComboBox` completely in the available space of `GridViewColumn`

This is my XAML.

```
<Window x:Class="WPFStarter.ComboInsideListView.ComboBoxInsideListViewUsingObject"
        x:Name="userControl"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="ComboBoxInsideListViewUsingObject" Height="300" Width="400">
    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=userControl, 
            Path=DataContext.Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=userControl, Path=DataContext.SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">                   
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                   <GridViewColumn Header="First Name"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=First}"/>
                   <GridViewColumn Header="Gender">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox x:Name="cmb_Gender" Width="75" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Gender}"                    
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=userControl, Path=DataContext.Genders}" GotFocus="ComboBox_GotFocus"         />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>

            </ListView.View>

        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Include the following style into the ListViews-resources. Then you can set the HorizontalAlignment-property of the ComboBox to `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` and it will do as you wish:

```
 <ListView.Resources>
          <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
          </Style>
 </ListView.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is working fine, but its still leaving some margin between the Combo and the Cell border. Is there a way to remove that?

Comment: You can try changing the ControlTemplate: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788717.aspx

Comment: Thanks, this link helped. Marking your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmb_Gender" Width="75" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Gender}"                    
    ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=userControl, Path=DataContext.Genders}" 
    GotFocus="ComboBox_GotFocus" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
```